# How to execute tor browser with the system tor service?

Tags: internet, browser, tor

The tor browser downloaded for Linux is launching a new Tor session with a new `torrc`.

If the tor service (installed with `apt-get install tor` and launched with `service tor start`)  is running, tor browser can simply not start.

**How can I modify the downloaded tor browser files in order to use the system tor service instead of the instance launched with `start-tor-browser`?**

Comment: https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/13211/how-to-make-tor-browser-work-with-the-system-tor-service-rather-than-the-tor-ser